# Remove default "Home" link?

Tags: 8, navigation

In Drupal 8, there is a 'Home' link in the "Main Navigation" menu provided by core. However, you can only disable this link, you cannot delete it.

How can I remove it? I don't need it and would rather just delete the menu link but the admin is prohibiting it. I had an issue where a content editor tried to set the menu link of a node to 'Home (Disabled)' by mistake - which caused a WSOD I have not yet diagnosed (somewhere when rendering the menu and/or breadcrumb on the page). Changing the menu link to `<Main Navigation>` root fixed this behavior, but I don't want it to happen again, so, I would like to delete it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I opened a drupal.org [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/2838106) on 20 december 2016 for this exact same request. The patch passes all tests and is now in the "Needs review" stage. Feel free to test the patch and mark the issue as RTBC.

Comment: Oh wow, nice. It has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: @wim is there any update on this? I'm very new to Drupal and I'm facing this issue. I noticed that there's a 'Work in PROGRESS' patch solution, but has no documentation yet, or at least I couldn't find it. Or is it there any way to 'fork' your solution (if your solution viable)?

Comment: @LucaciSergiu As you noticed, the issue is still a work in progress. The only workaround is to disable the existing Home link. If you want to rename it, you'll have to create a new menu item instead and point it to <front>.

Comment: @wim thank you for your answer. Yeah, that's my current approach, I disabled it manually, even though my ideal solution would be change via core commands.