# Bartik Home link to be uppercase

Tags: 8, navigation

How can I make "home" link on bartik menu uppercase and instead name it "front page"?
I tried by going to edit it at structure-menus-main navigation and i cannot because it says
"This link is provided by the Standard module. The title and path cannot be edited."
I created a subtheme of bartik. What should i write there in order to change it?
Thank you.I am using Drupal8.

Comment: By the way, how can i make different size and font all menu items?

Comment: you would do that with CSS.  Ex: `.region-primary-menu .menu-item { font-size: 30px; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to the Q [Remove default “Home” link?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225255/remove-default-home-link/225256#225256). You can not alter that menu item. The only way to fix this is to disable the existing "Home" link, and create a new one instead according to your specifications.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to `admin/structure/menu/manage/main` and disable the `Home` menu item
2. Add a new menu item at `admin/structure/menu/manage/main/add` and fill in the options like this:

[image: Home link]

3. Click `Save` and you're done

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  no i don't want to remove the "home" link.I need to have it with capital letters because the rest of my menu items are capitalized.Plus i would like to rename it "FRONT PAGE" and make it red color.Any idea how to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer with detailed instructions on how to do that.

Comment: A million thanks!It works!I wish you a very nice day!